# JQuery Finding Current Page URL

Tags: jquery, href, attr

The problem I am having is my website uses iFrames. So this current code doesn't get the correct url, it just gets desirednoise.com as the page URL. Even though user is on a specific post.

```
jQuery('#player-facebook').on('click', function() {
var anchor = jQuery('#player-controls-info a');
if (anchor.attr('href') == '#') {
    var fbText = document.title;
    var fbUrl = window.location.href;
} else {
    var fbText = "I'm listening to " + anchor.text().substr(13);
    var fbUrl = anchor.attr('href');
}
var fbParams = {u: fbUrl,
                t: fbText};
jQuery(this).attr('href', 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?'+jQuery.param(fbParams));
  });
  Player.playButton = jQuery('#player-play');
```

Is there another command besides. .attr('href') i could use?

This code goes to my custom website music player, its supposed to share the song its currently playing which = the page url of the post. Its a music blog

Comment: move away from using iframes

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the current URL of an iFrame if it's outside of the originating domain. It is a security limitation.

Read more about same-origin policy here:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy